# Which IDE or Tool can I use to code ASP.NET applications on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10

I want to code in ASP.NET but I don't know which IDE to use

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always use Visual Studio Code, it is neat and you can download many things for it.
[For more info look here](https://code.visualstudio.com/b) and to you can Download deb package [from here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/?dv=linux64_deb).